# Scrapy Python can‘t extract links with more stable xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, lxml

I‘m Building a scraper for this [website](https://startbase.com/startups). I‘m using Python and scrapy Shell to extract the data that I want: xpath would be: `//a[@class=“sb-card sb-card-company site-1x1 with-hover]/@href“`

Using `response.xpath(‘//a[@class=“sb-card sb-card-company site-1x1 with-hover]/@href“‘` returns `[]`

I tried using `contains(@class,“sb-card-company“)` with the same result. Using other containers in the same way, changed nothing. Using a different page also had no effect. Using hard nodes instead worked but I‘m curious about what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with xpath. It's a [dynamically-loaded content](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html) issue.

Here's an example of how you can get it from the json file:

```
scrapy shell

In [1]: url='https://www.startbase.de/api/companies/?format=json&display=small&sort=company.startbase_score&sort-direct
   ...: ion=desc&page=1&limit=21&filters={%22company.type%22:%22startup%22,%22startup_profile.industry_id%22:[10]}'

In [2]: headers = {
   ...: "Accept": "application/json",
   ...: "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   ...: "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   ...: "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
   ...: "Connection": "keep-alive",
   ...: "Content-Type": "application/json",
   ...: "DNT": "1",
   ...: "Host": "www.startbase.de",
   ...: "Pragma": "no-cache",
   ...: "Referer": "https://www.startbase.de/startups/?listOptions%5Bcompany-startup%5D=%7B%22version%22%3A1.3%2C%22sor
   ...: t%22%3A%22company.startbase_score%22%2C%22sortDirection%22%3A%22desc%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22small%22%2C%22item
   ...: sPerPage%22%3A21%2C%22page%22%3A1%2C%22userLocation%22%3Anull%2C%22filters%22%3A%7B%22startup_profile.industry_
   ...: id%22%3A%5B10%5D%7D%7D",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
   ...: "Sec-GPC": "1",
   ...: "TE": "trailers",
   ...: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.372
   ...: 9.169 Safari/537.36",
   ...: "X-KL-Ajax-Request": "Ajax_Request"
   ...: }

In [3]: req = scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers)

In [4]: fetch(req)
2021-10-16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.startbase.de/api/companies/?format=json&display=small&sort=company.startbase_score&sort-direction=desc&page=1&limit=21&filters=%7B%22company.type%22:%22startup%22,%22startup_profile.industry_id%22:[10]%7D> (referer: https://www.startbase.de/startups/?listOptions%5Bcompany-startup%5D=%7B%22version%22%3A1.3%2C%22sort%22%3A%22company.startbase_score%22%2C%22sortDirection%22%3A%22desc%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22small%22%2C%22itemsPerPage%22%3A21%2C%22page%22%3A1%2C%22userLocation%22%3Anull%2C%22filters%22%3A%7B%22startup_profile.industry_id%22%3A%5B10%5D%7D%7D)

In [5]: json_data = response.json()

In [6]: for company in json_data['body']['items']:
    ...:     print(company['company.url'])
    ...:
/organization/creditshelf/
/organization/amafin-gmbh/
/organization/fincompare/
/organization/epap/
/organization/clearvat/
/organization/51nodes/
/organization/altruja-gmbh/
/organization/flexvelop/
/organization/coin-analyst-ug/
/organization/caya/
/organization/rubarb/
/organization/memrange/
/organization/sevdesk-sevenit/
/organization/getsafe/
/organization/xavin/
/organization/giromatch/
/organization/digi-bel-projekt-von-meeting-minds/
/organization/digioptions/
/organization/trafinscout/
/organization/tangany-gmbh/
/organization/kiwi-financial-living/
```